# Rename/move (mv) multiple files starting with name

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

I'm trying to rename multiple files that match a pattern in one directory.

Files:

```
stack_overflow_one.xml
stack_overflow_two.xml
stack_overflow_one.html
```

I would like to rename `stack_overflow` to `heap_graph`

```
heap_graph_one.xml
heap_graph_two.xml
heap_graph_one.html
```

I have tried the following:

Using `rename`:

```
rename stack_overflow heap_graph stack_overflow* # returns 'The syntax of the command is incorrect.'
```

Using `for` loop in Bash

```
# how can I write this in one line? I've tried wrapping in one line, but also does not work
for i in stack_overflow* do
    mv "$i" "${i/stack_overflow/heap_graph}"
done
```

However, none of these are working.

Comment: There are a number of different implementations of `rename` floating around, supporting different sintaxes — on my PC the syntax is `rename s/stack_overflow/heap_graph/ stack_overflow*`

Comment: Use semicolons in your for-loop to write it on one line: `for foo in bar; do something; done`

Comment: If you found any of the given answers to be useful, do see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a trivial syntax error in the `for` loop. The rest of your script should work fine without any problem.

```
for i in stack_overflow*; do
#                      ^^^ missing semi-colon
# The below condition to handle graceful loop termination when no files are found
    [ -f "$i" ] || continue
    mv "$i" "${i/stack_overflow/heap_graph}"
done
```

---

As noted by [ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti) below if you are in the bourne again shell `bash` and not the `POSIX` bourne shell (`sh`) for which the solution above is portable, you can use special globbing options to avoid the condition of having to deal with case when no files are returned by the glob.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in stack_overflow*; do
    mv "$i" "${i/stack_overflow/heap_graph}"
done

shopt -u nullglob
```

The `-s` option sets it and `-u` unsets it. More on `shopt` built-in from the [GNU bash page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

Answer (score 0):

The semi-common utility [mmv](https://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html)
([article](https://www.cgarbs.de/blog/archives/430-mmv-mass-rename-of-files-and-more!.html))
is useful for the "multi-move" case you've described.

```
$ mmv -n 'stack_overflow_*' 'heap_graph__#' # remove -n after testing
mv -- stack_overflow_one.html heap_graph_one.html
mv -- stack_overflow_one.xml heap_graph_one.xml
mv -- stack_overflow_two.xml heap_graph_two.xml
```

As you can see, it's just calling down to `mv` multiple times for the
**pattern(s) matched**.

The `*` is a wildcard like Bash uses, but it's quote-escaped to be
passed to `mmv`.  The `_#` is the reference to the match, also escaped
(though the docs suggest `#1` would work instead).

This family of commands is also handy for copying (`cp`) and linking
(`ln`).

---

If you happen to have Zsh (a common Bash upgrade/replacement), you've
already got `zmv`, which would similarly do the job with:

```
% zmv -n 'stack_overflow_(*)' 'heap_graph_$1'
```